# Invalid permission from Lambda to MongoDB in EC2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have created a Lambda Function which intends to connect to MongoDB running on EC2.

I have followed some tutorials and guaranteed that:

- Lambda and EC2 run in the same VPC
- Lambda has configured EC2's subnet
- Lambda has its own security group my-lambda-sg
- Lambda's security group is allowed in EC2's security group inbounds rules for MongoDB's port as a "Custom TCP Rule"
- Lambda's role has assigned permission AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole

However, I am stil unable to connect from the lambda to the MongoDB in EC2. When I run a Test in the Lambda I get:

```
START RequestId: f0869292-5207-11e8-85d2-cba0eb99208c Version: $LATEST
2018-05-07T15:04:29.117Z    567951c4-5207-11e8-ba43-0314179d2bf5    { MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [IP:port] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 0 to IP:port timed out]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:503:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:326:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:317:30)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:256:10)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:420:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:317:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:277:5)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  message: 'failed to connect to server [IP:port] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 0 to IP:port timed out]' }
END RequestId: f0869292-5207-11e8-85d2-cba0eb99208c
```

From API Gateway I get

```
You do not have permission to perform this action
```

And from the browser I get:

```
{"message": "Endpoint request timed out"}
```

Other Lambda's not accessing EC2 are working fine.

Any idea what could I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. All requisites above are ok. I just needed to use the internal IP of the EC2 instead the external one in the MongoDB URL connection, to be considered a call within the VPC, as I found here [AWS Lambda unable to access EC2 port within the same VPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39945168/aws-lambda-unable-to-access-ec2-port-within-the-same-vpc)